# How can I wrap the Sitecore 8 itemWebApi to apply custom business logic to API responses?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I have a requirement to build a service endpoint to provide specific Sitecore 8.0 items (containing a given field value in a given branch of the content tree) to requesting mobile app clients. Encapsulating this logic (and perhaps some other calculations, etc) means the out-of-the-box API is not suitable.

I'd like to mimic an existing SOAP service exposed by another CMS, however I'm not above using a modified version of the RESTful itemWebApi if it confers greater code reusability or upgrade-safety.

Based on my research thusfar, it would appear my options are to build a custom handler, a completely separate asmx service (ala [this approach](http://rostacik.net/2013/01/26/painless-and-easy-way-to-json-endpoint-in-sitecore-aka-your-own-api-for-sitecore-in-few-easy-steps/)), or to build a custom controller (similar to [this custom Web API controller method](http://mikerobbins.co.uk/2015/04/12/add-custom-web-api-controller-to-sitecore-solution/)).

Overriding or replacing the default pipeline processors for the itemWebApi does not seem viable, as I don't want to replace/modify the OOB API if I can avoid it.

Has anyone with the same type of requirement for Sitecore 8 found a better approach?

Comment: There's also the entity and item service in Sitecore 7.5 onwards. Worth investigating if you haven't already. Mike has a good post on this http://mikerobbins.co.uk/2015/01/06/entityservice-sitecore-service-client/.

Comment: This looks like a great option, thanks. It allows you to create your own business entities to which sitecore item objects can be mapped, which is exactly what I'm looking to do.

Comment: Great! Glad I could help. It seems to be under documented, but quite useful. Could you possibly mark the comment as helpful? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach I chose was to create a separate service "router" developed using the adapter pattern to be consumed by our mobile app clients. The router in turn calls the Sitecore ItemWebApi.

This fit my needs the best as it is completely decoupled from the Sitecore application and the client can be modified if necessary without impacting the endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

It would also be worth looking to EntityService within Sitecore.Services.Client in Sitecore 8. Its a Web API based service but has more flexibility over the standard Sitecore Item Web API because you can define your model and the business logic yourself.

I can see you have mention my other blog post on adding a custom Web API controller. Enitity Service is different, it's a framework by Sitecore to achieve a standard way of creating custom web service for Sitecore.

I have written a blog post on EntityService. It has both a Javascript and standard rest based API to communicate with the service too.

http://mikerobbins.co.uk/2015/01/06/entityservice-sitecore-service-client/

Example Application here: https://github.com/sobek1985/EntityServiceDemo

And a few more posts on advanced features in Entity Service: http://mikerobbins.co.uk/category/sitecore/sitecore-service-client/